# Connect a React app and a NextJs app together

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a react dashboard, and I want to create a link to a nextjs App in the dashboard itself. The NextJs app will be in a different codebase.

I don't have a requirement for shared data between these two apps.

Do I just create an external link to the next app from the react app or do I have to achieve microfrontend here?

Comment: Just use the most basic `<a href="path_to_next_js_app"/>`?

Answer (score 0):

I try apply API Routing of NextJS for combine React Dashboard into NextJS and it's solved issue for me.
These steps I did:

1. Build React app to get folder *build*
2. Copy build folder into source NextJS. (ex: /static/admin)
3. In *pages*, create *api* folder then create dashboard.js file. This file will readFileAsync build of React.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6B3Ko.png)
4. Config next.config.js: modify url api/dashboard to /dashboard.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kF7H.png)
5. Run source and try access to url /dashboard.
   https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/api-routes